# Is $f$ differentiable at point?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

Let $f : [0, 1]\to\Bbb R$ $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0,&x=0\\\frac{1}{n},&x\in\left(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}\right),n\in\Bbb N\end{cases}$$ Is $f$ differentiable at a point?

I have tried using the method of determining whether the $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$ exists, and simplified it to $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{n}$, but I'm not sure if I can just say $f(x)=\frac{1}{n}$ and disregard the the fact $x\in\left(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}\right]$.

I also thought I could maybe use the Localization lemma, but I think I would be correct in saying there is no open set including zero in $[0,1]$, so that wouldn't be possible.

I'm fairly new to real analysis and have never had to determine whether a function like this is differentiable at a point. Thank you

Comment: Your question will be much easier to read if you use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset the mathematical formulas.

Comment: ok thank you ill try that

Comment: Is $f$ differentiable at a point? Well it's constant on lots of intervals, so yes it's differentiable at lots of points.

Answer (score 1):

Any number $x \in (0,1]$ belongs to $(\frac  1 {n+1},\frac  1 n]$ for some $n$. Consider $\frac {f(x)-f(0)} {x-0} =\frac {1/n} x$. This lies between $\frac {n+1} n$ and $1$ because $x \in (\frac  1 {n+1},\frac  1 n)$. Hence $|\frac {f(x)-f(0)} {x-0}-1| \leq \frac 1 n$. Note that $\frac  1 {n+1} <x$ so $n >\frac 1  x -1$. From this we get $\frac  1 n <\frac  x {1-x}$. This proves that $|\frac {f(x)-f(0)} {x-0}-1|<\epsilon$ whenever $\frac  x {1-x} <\epsilon$ or $x <\frac {\epsilon} {1+\epsilon}$. Take $\delta=\frac {\epsilon} {1+\epsilon}$ in the definition of $f'(0)$

Comment: @11carda Do you want more details? Feel free to ask for any clarification.